# I'm unable to install "Eclipse IDE for Android Developers"on windows7.

Tags: android

When i tried to uninstall available softwares in eclipse, it unstalled all except "Eclipse ide for android developers". When i try to uninstall this , it gives me a error " error while uninstalling ide" "uninstalling software has encountered a problem"

Comment: Please state your question. This question doesn't have a purpose.

Comment: Download zip file from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download . Extract it to start using it. Delete the folder when done. Since you just extracted it, not installed it, you just delete it, not try to uninstall it.

Comment: If you are unable to install SDK in ECLIPSE for android development , try downloading Android Studio it is also used to develop android application.
from this link : (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to download the ADT Bundle for a quick start in developing apps. The bundle includes the essential Android SDK components and a version of the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android Developer Tools) to streamline your Android app development.
Follow this [Link1](http://www.scringo.com/blog/how-to-install-the-android-sdk/)

OR

[Link2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidInstallation/article.html)